# In app purchase not working in released version

Tags: iphone

My app passed review of apple and was released. But I've got some mails from users, that in app purchase doesn't work! When I install my app by Build And Run from Xcode it's work great! Is there any logical reason to this? Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple took 1 day to enable in-App purchase once the app go live... Even i have faced the problem.

If your in App purchase works fine in sandbox mode... Just wait for 24 hours It will be solved.

Comment: In iTunes Connect products has "Ready for Sale" status. But I hope your right, else boss gonna kill me! :(

Comment: If it is "Ready for Sale"... You don't have to worry.

Comment: One day to enable in-app purchase ? This is really a huge bug, no ? Are you sure it happens all the time ? Is there anything to do to avoid this bug ?

Comment: Happens in December 2015 also - apparently.

Answer (score 1):

"doesn't work" isn't the most helpful of descriptions. I presume you have downloaded the release version yourself and tested it? What happens when you do it?

Is there any server side support for delivering the product? If so presumably you can check the logs to see if there is anything wrong there?

Comment: Right. I have server side that brings me the products ID's. I verify them with Apple. But it's works great in development version. In relase - nope.

Comment: Be more precise. What happens server side then for the release version? Do you get a receipt to verify? Do you get any communication from the app? It is probably just an apple delay but you could log things better in the app to help with this in a future release (eg using Flurry).

Comment: The server work it is also for release version and also for development. I use simple get method that brings me product IDs from server when app launches. I sure it's just an apple delay...I already wrote them a letter. Hope it will help.