# In-app purchase failing in store version of app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

In-app purchase is not working in the version of the app downloaded through the store.  This works perfectly in the test-flight version.

You see that the price is (null) and then the purchase itself doesn't go through.

When creating the app in itunesconnect there was no option to add in-app purchase to the app in the main developer page as detailed in page 22 of the manual [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide.pdf)

It all works perfectly in the sandbox. I even tried developer rejecting the review, to see if that would help as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366184/in-app-purchases-cannot-be-added-to-this-version-because-it-has-already-been-sub).

It did not help.

Is the document out of date? Am I doing something wrong? I have resubmitted a new app with new features as well as a different in-app purchase to see if we can get more debug info or if it will just start working.

There’s [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355442/in-app-purchase-not-working-in-released-version) also, which means we may just need to be patient.  However, it's been almost 48 hours as of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took about 48 hours, or perhaps a little longer, but the in-app purchases are now live.